# Setting reminder for last day of the month

Tags: slack, slack-commands

Is there a Slack reminder for `last day of the month` so that the reminder will occur on the 31st, 30th, or the 28th depending on the month?

Does something like `/remind @channel to do X on the last day of the month` work?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way but i could not find the best one to do it:

```
/remind @someone [What] on the 28th of every month
```

This will remind you on the 28th day of every month. Unfortunately there is no way of working this around. You can set a reminder for every 1st day of the month too:

```
/remind @someone [What] every month
```

You can set a reminder for every month but its not that easy to manage:

```
/remind @someone [What] on the 31st of every January
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax seems to work in setting a reminder for the last day of every month:

```
/remind @someone [What] on the 31st of every month
```

Comment: But what would happen if a month only has 30 days?

Comment: I'm unsure but I'll find out what happens this month since February 2020 only has 29 days.

Comment: @EdBlankenship So what happened m8?

Comment: /remind me “Submit Timecard” at noon on 28 Feb 2021

Comment: /remind me “Submit Timecard” at noon on 28 Feb 2025

Comment: /remind me “Submit Timecard” at noon on 28 Feb 2029

Comment: @EdBlankenship what's the status?

Comment: @Holene I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  What's the status of what exactly?

Comment: @EdBlankenship What happened in February 2020? Or in any other month with less than 31 days 

Comment: @Holene oh gosh, I'm honestly not sure. I don't remember  I'm hoping someone else can contribute what they've learned about this particular scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I've just created 12 reminders for myself for the next year

```
/remind @yourname to "Fill time-report" at 9:00 on Sep 30
/remind @yourname to "Fill time-report" at 9:00 on Oct 31 # Note that October has 31 days
...
```

This way you can adjust for last weekday of the month being a holiday in your country